# Avoid Date Overlapping using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class with properties 'code','fromDate' and 'toDate' and i need to insert one new record using JPA such a way that for given code date range should not overlap.

```
For example 
If code- ABC of date range 01/Feb/2014-10/Feb/2014 exist in DB.
I am inserting code ABC again with date range 
03/Feb/2014-07/Feb/2014 should not accept -  from date and to date is Within existing Date range
28/Jan/2014-02/Feb/2014 should not accept -   to date is Within existing Date range
05/Feb/2014-21/Feb/2014 should not accept -   From date is Within existing Date range
01/Jan/2014-28/Feb/2014 should not accept -   The existing date range is within the given date range so Overlapping will happen.
```

Suppose the data need to be inserted is in a viewObject with similar properties.
Please help me to do the validation for date overlapping using JPA predicates

Answer (score 2):

Before saving the new object you can query the DB to check if an 'overlapping' records exists.
If, a record is returned, then do not save the new object, else save;

```
String query = "SELECT ent FROM Entity ent WHERE ent.fromDate <= :toDate AND ent.toDate >= :fromDate WHERE ent.id = :entId";

List<Entity> overlappingRecords = JPA.em().createQuery(query).setParameter("entId", id).setParameter("fromDate", fromDate).setParameter("toDate", toDate).getResultList();

if(overlappingRecords.isEmpty())
   //Over lap does not exist
else
   //Over lap exists
```

This query assumes rejection of edges overlapping exactly.